# Why did December owe September?-Spoilers

Tags: fringe

In the final episode of Fringe (or maybe the second-to-last, I forget), September (Donald) goes to December and asks a favor of him, stating "You owe me."  How/what did December owe?

Answer (score 3):

September was aware that all of the members of the Observer team were contaminated (with emotions) by being in the past. Starting with the actions of August.

He didn't mention this when he was being punished/reverted for having emotions.

Comment: Can you back this up?

Comment: It is mentioned in the last series when September explains what happened to him for repeated interference with the timelines.